# Excel - extracting numeric value from cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

All,

I have a workbook of values laid out like so:

```
 |    A   |     B    |    C    |
1| VAR - 2| VAR - 18 | VAR - 7 |
```

I am trying to extract the values from A1:C1 and total them up in D1. So D1 should be 27. Anyone know how to do this? I started with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(- -ISNUMBER(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$200),1)+0))
```

But this seems to only be calculating the number of digits, not the total value. Any ideas?

Darius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `D1` Enter

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1:C1,--FIND("-",A1:C1,1)+1,255)),--MID(A1:C1,--FIND("-",A1:C1,1)+1,255),0))`

Then click anywhere inside `D1` and hit  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

*255 here is the number of characters after `-` in the cell*

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do!

Comment: SUMPRODUCT within an array formula is somewhat tautological. In array formulas, SUM will always suffice in place of SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```
{=SUM(VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(A1:C1,2))))}
```

Note that it is an array formula, so be sure to hit ctrl-shift-enter when inside the cell.

If your number could be longer than 2 digits, then this may be more appropriate (general)

```
{=SUM(VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(A1:C1,LEN(A1:C1)-6))))}
```

Comment: This assumes all numbers are 1 or 2 digits long.

Comment: Because I want to maintain the "VAR". This three letter word varies across the spreadsheet and needs to be there unfortunately.

Comment: The formula I provided does not disturb the VAR.

Comment: Do I use it with those brackets surrounding it?

Comment: No, once you hit `ctrl-shift-enter` while your cursor is inside the formula, then the brackets will appear automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your formula... 
***USE CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER to calculate!***

it will work with any mix of characters and numbers. It will extract the number and dispose of the characters

`=(1*MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1))))+(1*MID(B1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(B1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(B1,ROW($1:$9),1))))+(1*MID(C1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(C1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(C1,ROW($1:$9),1))))`

Comment: Is there any way to do that all in one? Like A1:C1?

Comment: Do you want to sum them up, right? To do the summation, your numbers must be separated into parts, so those parts could be added together...

Comment: I do, but I didn't exactly want to duplicate that for each column (eg. if it expanded all the way to Q1). Is there absolutely no other way?

Answer (score 0):

or you could get the MORFUNC addon* and simply do:

`{=SUM(VALUE(REGEX.MID(A1:C1,"[0-9]")))}`

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)